# Vigilar proceso al momento de cerrar C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un problema con el siguiente codigo, lo que intento es que un proceso llamando **ffmpeg** que corre dentro de sistema se cierre dando un aviso que ya se termino el trabajo.

```
private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnIniciar.Enabled = false;
            btnCancelar.Enabled = true;
            Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            //psi->WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle::Hidden;
            psi.Arguments = "/k ffmpeg -i " + txtArchivo.Text + " proceso\\video.mp4";
            p.StartInfo = psi;
            p.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            while(procesoFFMPEG())
            {
                lblEstado.Text = "Estado: En ejecucion...";
            }
            lblEstado.Text = "Estado: Finalizado";
            //p.Kill();
        }

public Boolean procesoFFMPEG()
        {
            if(Process.GetProcessesByName("ffmpeg").Length > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

El problema es que al ejecutar el programa este se **frizea** hasta que el proceso **ffmpeg** se cierra.

en que me equivoco?

saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás bloqueando el hilo que se encarga del *UI*, por lo tanto la interfaz de usuario se queda frita.

Usa un `BackgroundWorker`, tendrás que afinarlo un poco, pero sería algo así:

```
private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    btnIniciar.Enabled = false;
    btnCancelar.Enabled = true;

    lblEstado.Text = "Estado: En ejecucion...";
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    psi.Arguments = "/k ffmpeg -i " + txtArchivo.Text + " proceso\\video.mp4";
    p.StartInfo = psi;
    p.Start();

    var worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker() {
        WorkerReportsProgress = true,
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
    };
    btnCancelar.OnClick => (s, a) => worker.CancelAsync();

    worker.DoWork += (s, a) => {
        int n=0;
        while (procesoFFMPEG()) {
            if (worker.CancellationPending) { a.Cancel = true;  break; }
            worker.ReportProgress((n++)%100);
        }
    };
    worker.ProgressChanged += (s, a) => { } 

    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,a) => {
        lblEstado.Text = "Estado: Finalizado";
    }
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Ten en cuenta que el código se ejecutará en otro hilo, y dentro del `DoWork` no podrás acceder a elementos de la interfaz de usuario, salvo que uses el método `Invoke` del *form* o el control al que quieras acceder, para que se ejecute ese código en el *thread* que maneja el *UI*.

```
control.Invoke((MethodInvoker) (() => control.Text = "new text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema probablemente está en tu bucle `while(procesoFFMPEG())..`. 
Este bucle esta bloqueando el hilo principal de la aplicación, no dejando que el UI se actualice.

Prueba a meter dentro de ese bucle un `Thread.Sleep` o un `Application.DoEvents()`, lo que hará que el UI tenga tiempo de procesar los eventos.

**Edit**

TL;DR; En el 99% de los casos,la forma mas correcta de afrontar estos problemas es la que indica @Blau en su respuesta.

Como bien apuntaba @Blau, [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx) tiene varias contraindicaciones que merecen ser apuntadas. Puede provocar un problema de reentrada, ya que si alguno de los mensajes procesados durante su ejecución provoca que se dispare algun evento de la aplicación, pueden ejecutarse otras partes del código y causar errores dificiles de depurar. Por eso Microsoft no recomienda su uso **para operaciones que tarden mucho tiempo**. En esos casos, es preferible un `BackgroundWorker` o utilizar `async/await`.

Como explicación adicional, existe un debate sobre si `BackgroundWorker` ha quedado, a partir de .Net 4.5, obsoleto. En general, si usamos .Net 4.5, hay cierto consenso en que es preferible usar `async/await`,sobre todo si el trabajo que se debe realizar comprende operaciones de entrada/salida. Para casos como el que nos ocupa, el uso de `BackgroundWorker` es correcto.

Sin embargo, y para defender un poco mi respuesta, para bucles que vayan a tardar muy poco tiempo, `DoEvents` es perfectamente aceptable en mi opinión.

Comment: Gracias me sirvio `Application.DoEvents()`

Comment: Eso no es lo mas apropiado... si que despacha todo lo que haya pendiente... pero te puede ocasionar problemas,,, lo correcto es usar un segundo thread... mediante un BackgroundWorker o una Task... o como quieras....

Comment: @blau para una tarea tan sencilla,`DoEvents` es suficiente. Utilizar un `BackgroundWorker` para algo asi es como matar moscas a cañonazos. Ya se que `DoEvents` tiene muy mala prensa,pero para un bucle sencillo como este funciona perfectamente. Si microsoft lo usa en `ShowDialog`,tan peligroso no será :)

Comment: Tambien desactiva el resto de ventanas...

Comment: Y el backgroundworker esta hecho para eso precisamente... no matas moscas a cañonazos ... las matas con insecticida

Comment: Efectivamente @blau. En ningun caso digo que `DoEvents` sea la solucion correcta en todos los casos, pero aqui simplemente es un bucle que espera a que termine otro proceso,lo que no creo que tarde mucho tiempo y que de problemas. Para casos mas complejos,por supuesto se debe usar un Task o BackgroundWorker

Comment: Muchas suposiciones... con lo sencillo que es hacer las cosas bien,,, ;) Un saludo